# Select item in list, show text in text area

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jlist, jtextarea

I am working on a rough draft of a gui, looking at different options. I was hopping to use a `JList` to show text in a `JTextArea` based on what *item* is selected. You can see the `JList` on the left and the `JTextArea` in the center.

Or is there a better way to do this? I am already using tabs that will be used for a broad category. I saw that the `CardLayout`, but don't quite like the look. Any tips?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can use a ListSelectionListener to set the content accordingly..

```
 JList list = new JList(someArrayofData);
 list.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener(){
      public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e){
            int selectedIndex = list.getSelectedIndex();
            //refresh the content based on the index
            setContent(selectedIndex);
      }
});
```

Its hard to say which gui layout will work the best for you without knowing what the application is for.

Comment: that's fine, i just needed a direction to go when google failed me. still new to java and there is a lot of library to learn. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use the position of the item that is selected in the `JList` to tell you what text to set in the `JTextArea` in the middle.  Setup a `listener` on the `JList` and check for `onChange` events.  Grab the index of the selected element.  In an array somewhere, use that index to grab the relevant text that is mapped to that `JList` element that was selected.  Then set the text of the `JTextArea` to what you grabbed from the array.