# JList is hiding the selected element

Tags: java, swing, visibility, jlist

I have a JList that is built off of a DefaultListModel.  I also have a ListSelectionListener added onto the list. I don't know why, but whenever I select an item on the list, it correctly chooses it and highlights/emboldens the line it's on, but doesn't show the text.  I know I've selected the item, but all I see is a bar over it.  I'm very new to GUI in general, so any help would be appreciated.

This is my all of my code that involves GUI (I think).  Like I said, I'm new to this so most of it is auto-generated and it's REALLY sloppy.

```
public GUIlab_Cowley() {
    this.setSize(480, 360);

    //options bar
    JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
    setJMenuBar(menuBar);

    //file
    JMenu mnFile = new JMenu("File");
    menuBar.add(mnFile);

    //file>exit
    JMenuItem mntmExit = new JMenuItem("Exit");
    mnFile.add(mntmExit);
    mntmExit.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });
    getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));

    //additems menu
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setBackground(SystemColor.activeCaption);
    panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(125, 10));
    getContentPane().add(panel, BorderLayout.WEST);
    GridBagLayout gbl_panel = new GridBagLayout();
    gbl_panel.columnWidths = new int[]{0, 0};
    gbl_panel.rowHeights = new int[]{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
    gbl_panel.columnWeights = new double[]{1.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
    gbl_panel.rowWeights = new double[]{0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
    panel.setLayout(gbl_panel);

    //additem
    JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Add Item");
    btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) 
        {
            try{
                item newObject = new item(textField.getText(), textArea.getText());
                listModel.addElement(newObject);
                for(int a = 0; a < listModel.getSize()-1; a++)
                {
                    item temp = (item)listModel.getElementAt(a);
                    if(temp.getName().equals(newObject.getName()) && a != -1)
                    {
                        listModel.removeElement(newObject);
                        throw new TwoManyItemsException();
                        //i looked up how to use JOptionPane at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (TwoManyItemsException e)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "2 items in the list cannot have the same name",
                        "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                //i looked up how to use JOptionPane at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html
            }

            //I found .getText() at 
            //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5752307/how-to-retrieve-value-from-jtextfield-in-java-swing
            //original author - Harry Joy
        }
    });
    btnNewButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(125, 25));
    GridBagConstraints gbc_btnNewButton = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_btnNewButton.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 0);
    gbc_btnNewButton.gridx = 0;
    gbc_btnNewButton.gridy = 0;
    panel.add(btnNewButton, gbc_btnNewButton);

    //name the list item
    textField = new JTextField();
    textField.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(125, 20));
    GridBagConstraints gbc_textField = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_textField.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 0);
    gbc_textField.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    gbc_textField.gridx = 0;
    gbc_textField.gridy = 2;
    panel.add(textField, gbc_textField);
    textField.setColumns(10);

    //enter a description box
    textArea = new JTextArea();
    textArea.setSize(new Dimension(5, 1));
    textArea.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(5, 1));
    GridBagConstraints gbc_textArea = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_textArea.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    gbc_textArea.gridx = 0;
    gbc_textArea.gridy = 4;
    panel.add(textArea, gbc_textArea);


    //center panel
    final JPanel panel_1 = new JPanel();
    getContentPane().add(panel_1, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    panel_1.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));

    JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("Item List");
    lblNewLabel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(41, 25));
    lblNewLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    panel_1.add(lblNewLabel, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    //list panel
    list.setBackground(SystemColor.activeCaption);
    list.setSelectionBackground(SystemColor.activeCaption);
    list.setSelectionForeground(SystemColor.activeCaption);
    panel_1.add(list, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    JButton btnNewButton_1 = new JButton("Delete Item");
    btnNewButton_1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
        {
            System.out.println("Tried to remove something");
            listModel.removeElementAt(list.getSelectedIndex());
            //I looked at oracle's instructions, but I ended up using this answer on stackoverflow
            //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9402658/delete-selected-item-from-jlist
            //original author - Joop Eggen
        }
    });
    listModel.addListDataListener(new ListDataListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void contentsChanged(ListDataEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void intervalAdded(ListDataEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void intervalRemoved(ListDataEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            panel_1.repaint();
        }
        //i found addlistdatalistener here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ListModel.html
        //and followed the autogenerated stubs
    });
    panel_1.add(btnNewButton_1, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    JPanel panel_2 = new JPanel();
    getContentPane().add(panel_2, BorderLayout.EAST);
    panel_2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(125, 10));
    panel_2.setLayout(null);

    textPane = new JTextPane();
    textPane.setBounds(0, 0, 125, 301);
    list.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener()
    {
        public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e)
        {
            int selectedIndex = list.getSelectedIndex();
            item temp = (item)listModel.elementAt(selectedIndex);
            textPane.setText(temp.getDesc());



            //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11695454/select-item-in-list-show-text-in-text-area
            //original author - Joel
        }
    });
    panel_2.add(textPane);
}
```

Comment: I would be very useful to see your code...

Comment: which part, all of it or the selectionlistener?

Comment: Every part where you are creating and/or manipulating gui components, e.g. creating your JFrame, JPanel, JList, etc.

Comment: can you post "item" Class code?

Comment: You don't think `list.setSelectionBackground(SystemColor.activeCaption);` followed by `list.setSelectionForeground(SystemColor.activeCaption);`  would be a problem?

Comment: Like I said, I'm new to GUI so I actually didn't understand where the problem might be.  Yes, that was the problem.  Thank you very much.

Comment: Yep, that was it.  Thanks MadProgrammer